# Decode a message created using OpenSSL with a stored procedure in MySQL Community Server

Tags: mysql, openssl

I have a message I encoded using OpenSSL and my private key, I want to decode the message in a stored procedure in MySQL using the public key (which I will store in a table in MySQL).

Here is how I generate the message from the Linux command line...

```
echo "The message I want encoded" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey private_key.pem -out >(base64)
```

Here is the output it produces...

```
B7b2L7AMD7NBcg30N+DrO4gJFojzw06GKJFZTJsJCEjIeHBNjN2tUh7Nx18Y69wN342FhVQ4HYxv
A5+kVB5LN2v81R1y4qTn/z/PqPTVdAiH/F7zNb/XsrzkLhTCqHgCwxwRPuiR4PTZ8InSo4X88r68
v7LcQD58z20bLq98dcXmPRPpsLqwY4KSofSajkh4LZ4+K+5wiWRv0LyMnFtHCuc97Rafzm7kYf7c
Nvts0C3mmwieUXzBCJiunLw8Hn6waD451Kvm3cCjhyPIYOpyA5Vkzxb2XQy3KOpAHK8TOqdUI4Gy
TPK8OCBaEknM4ywF0AuMdpV9ntk0JfLAyka6WQ==
```

Now, if I pass that Base64 string into a procedure in MySQL with the public key, can I decode it?

Is this even possible? I can't find any examples. I am guessing that AES_DECRYPT is the command to use but I don't understand how or if that is even the right way to do this.

As I am in experimentation mode, I am doing all this manually so there is no specific language in mind other than the MySQL stored procedure that I will call in the end. But simple SQL will work to demonstrate how this might be done.

I just need a nudge to get started. For example, if I stored the public key in a variable named @pubkey and the message in a variable named @message, would I use some SQL like this?

```
select AES_DECRYPT(from_base64(@message),@pubkey) as result;
```

I tried just that and it wouldn't decode. So I assume there is more to it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found what I was looking for and it looks like MySQL Community Server does not support the featuers I was hoping for.

The features I want are only in MySQL Enterprise so to do what I am trying to do I will have to do the encryption/decryption on the application.

For anyone who is interested in the commands in question, feel free to checkout the MySQL site:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enterprise-encryption-functions.html

Comment: PS: I had the process wrong in my head anyway. You don't encrypt with the private key then decrypt with the public key. But you can SIGN small blocks in this way which for my application serves the same function.